# Error in displaying and getting the image from template to backend

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

127.0.0.1/:277 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Screenshot%20(13).png 404 (Not Found)
I have tried mostly everything but not able to find the solution.
I am new to Django and basically a beginner so help me to do this.
Tried mostly everything.
I have tried mostly everything but not able to find the solution.
I am new to Django and basically a beginner so help me to do this.
Tried mostly everything.

This is the image:

[image: 1]

**In my views.py**

```py
def addblog(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get('title', '')
        head0 = request.POST.get('head0', '')
        chead0 = request.POST.get('chead0', '')
        head1 = request.POST.get('head1', '')
        chead1 = request.POST.get('chead1', '')
        head2 = request.POST.get('head2', '')
        chead2 = request.POST.get('chead2', '')
        pub_date = request.POST.get('pub_date', '')
        thumbnail = request.POST.get('thumbnail', '')
        add = Blogpost(title=title, head0=head0, chead0=chead0, head1=head1, chead1=chead1, head2=head2, chead2=chead2, pub_date=pub_date, thumbnail=thumbnail)
        add.save()
        que = True
        return render(request, 'blog/addblog.html', {'que': que})
    return render(request, 'blog/addblog.html')
```

**In my models.py**

```py
class Blogpost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    head0 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    chead0 = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    head1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    chead1 = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    head2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    chead2 = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**In my settings.py**

```py
    DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y'
    DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%d-%m-%Y',   # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
]

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

**In my addblog.html**

```html
     <h3>Add Your Blog</h3>
    <form action="/blog/addblog/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name='title' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Head0</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="head0" name='head0' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Chead0</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chead0" name='chead0' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Head1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="head1" name='head1' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Chead1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chead1" name='chead1' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Head2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="head2" name='head2' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="title" >Chead2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chead2" name='chead2' placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
        </div>

<p>Enter Date: <input type = "date" id = "datepicker-3" ></p>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Select File</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail">
  </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: does this error occur when you submit your form to add data

Comment: yes it occurs when I submit data

Comment: while you enter the datefield do you type the date

Comment: I edited the image above please review it

Comment: then there will be a calendar icon in that datefield you can use that to select your date

Comment: I already did that but still this problem occurs.

Comment: did you change anything in your `settings.py`

Comment: just manually added DATE_FORMAT and DATE_INPUT_FORMAT

Comment: try removing that

Comment: Can't check it right now but straight away I can see your date input (html) has no name, you should probably add to it `name="pub_date"`, else date will be missing in the submitted form, may be the reason, you should try it.

Comment: @Harry I tried removing that but same error

Comment: Then you can try adding the date like `30 dec 2020`

Comment: @YuriNudelman id and name both added but still problem occurs

Comment: @Harry   Date format problem is resolved but my image is not coming in the template.

Comment: @YuriNudelman Date format problem is resolved but my image is not coming in the template

Comment: I think you need to add some staticfile configuration to do that

Comment: did that but image doesn't show

Comment: Sorry but I dont have anyother solutions

Comment: You should never change the question you should open a new question if you want to ask a new question

Comment: Can you share your project tree

Comment: I think you should change your `upload_to='shop/images ` to `upload_to='media'`